# How long have you been here?

Tags: grammar

Could this sentence mean - how long is your stay? and it is known that my stay is temporary

If "i have been on a holiday for two weeks" could be used when i am currently on a holiday.

Answer (score 4):

*How long have you been here* is asking for the time between when someone arrived, and when the current conversation is taking place (now).

For example, if you landed in New York on Monday, and you meet one of your American friends on Friday, who asks:

> How long have you been here?

Your response would be the amount of time since you landed, which generally includes the first day (or other unit of time) and doesn't include the current day (or other unit of time):

> I've been here for 4 days.